# Switched over js object to Ember Data model using Fixture Adapter and keep getting "Cannot call method 'findAll' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working through the Code School Ember.js course and I have a Product model that is being loaded via the Fixture Adapter. My issue is that whenever I click on the 'products' link, linking to '/products' I get an error reading:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'findAll' of undefined
```

My ProductsRoute looks like:

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('product');
    }
});
```

And the route fails to render.

Before I started using Ember Data and the Fixture adapter I was just using a js array of objects and calling it in the model: property of my Route object, which worked fine.

Here's my jsbin, minus the Ember Data Library:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zicofeku/1/edit

And here's an image of my console error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get all Product records? In this case just use `find` with no parameters. See [the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) for details.

Your code should look like:

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('product');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to retrieve all the Product records. I tried changing the method to .find, but I still get the error, "Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined". So I assume it has something to do with Product model. Perhaps the ordering of the adapter/model/fixtures/etc. in app.js?

Comment: You didn't have ember-data included in your page. I added <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script> below the ember include and it worked. In future, make sure you open up the console window in JSbin and your browser - should save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: And here's the fixed jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qeyovoje/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks very much. I had ember data in the head of my actual app, just not in the js bin, but it was a hardcoded file I got from github. I switched it out with the amazon hosted version and it worked. Not sure why, but I appreciate it.